# python3 class comparisons: object is both equal to and less than other

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison

Python3 changed the way classes implement comparators from a single `__cmp__` function to [6 possible functions](http://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html).  I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a couple of weird quirks that this creates.

For example, take this class:

```
from functools import total_ordering

class Class:
  def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b

  @total_ordering
  def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.c < other.c
```

In this, you can easily get two objects that are both equal to each other, AND where one is less than the other (e.g `Class(1,2,3)` and `Class(1,2,4)`).  Now you could easily argue that this is simply poor design.  You shouldn't have one comparator that uses different attributes than another, fine.  But now consider this slightly modified class:

```
from functools import total_ordering

class Class:
  def __init__(self, date, name, c):
    self.date = date
    self.name = name

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.date == other.date and self.name == other.name

  @total_ordering
  def __lt__(self, other):
return self.date < other.date
```

This class is clearly orderable (by date).  But I can also have two objects that are not equal to each other, but neither is less than the other (e.q. `Class(date(2018,8,14), 'Alice')` and `Class(date(2018,8,14), 'Bob')`).

I guess there's a couple questions here:

1. Is there guidance on the "proper" way to handle this new type of comparisons?
2. How would `sorted()` or `sort()` handle broken comparisons? Say, for instance, we create an object that is both less then AND greater than another (because we're stupid)? What happens under the covers?
3. What is the value of this new comparison method?  The link above simple states that "early in Python 2 development, it became apparent that only allowing three cases for the relative order of objects is too limiting", but does not elaborate.   It seems to me the potential dangers of this style greatly outweigh the benefits.

Comment: The proper way is to make sure that `a <= b` is consistent with `a == b and a < b`. Fix that, and points 2 and 3 are moot.

Comment: @chepner obviously, but I can imagine a useful scenario in which you want to have 2 things unequal, but neither greater or less than the other.  For instance, take the second example, but make the date `date_of_birth`.  You may want to sort your people by age, in which case an earlier birthdate means a person is "greater than" another, but two different people born on the same day are obviously not the same person, but neither is greater than the other.

Comment: Then you define a separate `key` function to pass to `sort` or `sorted`; you don't break your class's natural ordering.

Comment: A total ordering means that for *every* `a` and `b`, either `a < b`, `a == b`, or `a > b` is true. Don't use the `totalordering` decorator if you aren't actually defining a total order.

Comment: @chepner good to know.  But just for academic purposes, what will python actually try to do if you have items that are both less then and greater than others?

Comment: You can look at [the `functools` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/functools.py) to see how `totalordering` defines the missing comparison operators. After that, it just depends on which operators get called. For example, if you define `__lt__`, then `__gt__(a, b)` is effectively just `not (a < b) and a != b`.